# How do I substitute values appsettings.json in a test project in Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, integration-testing, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

### What do I have

- In my release pipeline I use IIS Web App Deployment Task that does a variable substitution in appsettings.json:

  [image: task screenshot]
- I want to run some integration and end to end tests:

  [image]

### Question

1. How do I replace settings appsettings.json related to my test projects.
2. How do I force the test runner to use a specific environment, e.g Staging, so that appsettings.Staging.json will is picked?

Comment: You can try to add a separate [file transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task. In addition, can you elaborate on the relationship between appsettings.json and test?

Comment: @HiGuy: That solves #1. I've solved #2 as well, but won't mark it as answer just yet, in case you have better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **How do I replace settings appsettings.json related to my test projects.**

   There is [File Trasnform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task that does the variable substitution exactly like IIS Web App Deployment Task but in a separate step.

---

2. **How do I force the test runner to use a specific environment, e.g Staging, so that appsettings.Staging.json will is picked?**

   Environment variables like ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT can be configured in a .runsettings file:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RunSettings>
      <RunConfiguration>
        <EnvironmentVariables>
          <ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>Development</ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT>
        </EnvironmentVariables>
      </RunConfiguration>
    </RunSettings>
   ```

   The value of environment variable can be then replaced in a separate pipeline step. I've used powershell task:

   ```
    steps:
    - powershell: |
       $fileName = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MyBuildArtifact/test.runsettings";
       [xml]$xml = Get-Content $fileName
       $xml.SelectSingleNode("//ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT").InnerText = "$(System.StageDisplayName)";
       $xml.Save($fileName);
      failOnStderr: true
      showWarnings: true
      displayName: 'Configure ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'
   ```

I also needed to make sure the test.runsettings file is included in my build artifact and configure the Visual Studio Test task to use that file